# How can I combine multiple base classes? c++

Tags: c++, class, linker

I started working on my first bigger project. I've created a handful of classes, inherited classes and split them all up in separate header files, cpp files and linked successfully. Testing my code I came to a problem I've not seen tutorials for (yet) because I don't even know what exactly should I look for. In the main exe I want to let the user to pick a role, which is one base class divided into inherited subclasses, and then give the user a weapon, which is a completely different class.

```
class Player_char{         //BASE CLASS
string name;
public:
void setStats(string Name...);     
};

class Catman:public Player_char{      //INHERITED CLASS
...
};

class Weapon{         //BASE CLASS
int damage;
public:
void setStats(int);
};

int main(){

Player_char *player;
Weapon hammer;

//if statement to let the user select between roles
player=new Catman;

//player(class) has hammer (another class)

}
```

I really just don't even know what exactly to look up. I hope this is clear enough. Essentially what I'm trying to achieve is `player.hammer.function();`

Comment: What is the expected output and how does it differ from current output? Also what is the current input?

Comment: Please try to create a [mre] to show us. And if you have build errors, then please copy-paste the full and complete build-log into your question as well.

Comment: Don't get too focused on inheritance. Aggregation/Mixin can be more maintainable. Even better, for bigger projects, learn about abstract baseclasses (interfaces), depenendency injection and unit testing. Also avoid naked raw owning pointers like "Player_char" either store multiple players in a std::vector, or (if you need polymorphism) at least use std::make_unique instead of using new/delete

Comment: @user12002570 I'm not super far into this but essentially I expect something like `player.hammer.function();`

Comment: Ok so you're really starting with C++ then?

Comment: You need to distinguish between *classes* and *objects*. `player` isn't a class, it's an object (or rather, a pointer to an object). Same with `hammer`, it's an object (not a pointer).

Comment: For your inheritance to work your Player_char class at least needs to have at least one  virtual method (and a virtual destructor). Side note stop using `using namespace std;`

Comment: As for your problem, it seem that your `Player_char` class should have a pointer to a `Weapon` object. That's called *aggregation*.

Comment: If you want the program to read data and, on the basis of that data, decide whether you want `player` to point at a `Catman` or some other class derived from `Player_char`, then look up "factory pattern".   There are - depending on your needs - various ways of achieving such a thing.

Comment: i hope you don't understand this wrongly, but you could start your programming journey at a simpler language than C++, maybe python or java or C#, and get the fundamentals of programming first such as inheritance and polymorphism and aggregation, then you could come back to C++ where you will learn about memory management and undefined behavior, at this point you have to figure it all at once, plus a lot of extra C++ specific gotchas like the rule of 5 and templates, it is hard to love programming when you are programming only in C++ as it gives you too much responsibilities.

Comment: What is the specific chapter in your C++ textbook where this practice problem is from? Here's the right way to learn C++: get a good textbook, open to Chapter 1, and keep working through the textbook's organized curriculum, which properly explained each C++ topic, in the orderly fashion, from the simplest to the most advanced. Here's the worst way to learn C++: think of a random program or a game, and then try to figure out how to write it in C++.